# How to do rest api get and post call using jdk 1.5.0

Tags: java, post, get, rest

my project is having jdk 1.5.0 with websphere 6.1 and Now i am trying to do rest api get and post calls to consume rest api. i am getting HttpClient and other jars error with Unsupported version.

How to do this with jdk 1.5

Comment: Downgrade to an older version of the http client library that supports 1.5? If you post the name of the library you are using (there are many) it is easier to help.

Comment: Websphere 6.1 was end of life in 2016. If you can you should migrate away from it. The rest of the Java ecosystem has long migrated to Java 8 so it might be very difficult to get current versions to work with Java 5/WS 6.1.